# Jar cannot find the path to the file inside

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, build-process

In my Maven project I have a properties file that has a property for a location of keystore file `file=filename.p12` (I think the file type doesn't really matter now).
The problem I have that when i built it with maven, I see that the file is inside the root of jar and when i run `java -jar the-jar-file.jar` I get the IO exception that the `filename.p12` is not found.

Everything runs fine in Eclipse, it finds the file and the application runs. Not to confuse somebody, I keep a copy of that `filename.p12` as well in `src/main/resources folder` so that the paths are resolved running in Eclipse and standalone. But this is going to be my other question.

What I can't do is to get the `filename.p12` as a resource, because I have external jar that gets as argument my properties file and then handles that properties file itself where the row `file=filename.p12` is. Why is the file not found inside the jar, even though I see it's there? My other property files that I have open with `Spring's ClassPathResource` run just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access internal/embedded resources you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` depending on your needs